# UIViewController integration in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to connect a UIViewController inside my SwiftUI project. I watched WWDC19 and some interesting articles, and I've tried two different approach:

1:

```
struct SwipingIntegratedController : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

   func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyUIViewController {
       return MyUIViewController()
   }


   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyUIViewController, context: Context) {
    
   }
}
```

With this approach I get a crash in my first UI element of `MyUIViewController` (Let's say there is view.backgroundColor = .white => crash).
So I guess something went wrong here ...

So I tried with the second approach:

2:

```
struct HomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
       return UIStoryboard(name: "MyView", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController").view
   }

   func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {
    
   }
}
```

With this approach everythings seems to works fine (no crash), but once my UIViewController has been instatiated, nothings seems to work. I've seen that there is a Coordinator in order to manage the logic, but all I have to do in this viewController is to press a button and go to a whole different flow made with UIKit.

So my question is , am I missing something? Why the first approach (which seems the correct one) crash? And why the second approach has a dead UiViewController with no action?

P.s.

This is where I get the crash with the first approach:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
        
   self.mainView.backgroundColor = Colors.white //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

And in the debugger all my UI element are like this:

```
myButton    UIButton?   nil
```

If I delete the `mainView` the crash will be on the following UI element!

Comment: What error message (or stack trace) do you get with the crash?

Comment: Hi @PhillipMills this is the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: And if I watch on the debugger below all my UI elements are nil. This is the first viewController of a storyboard, so nothing weird!

Comment: Can you post your code where you actually get the crash?

Comment: @koen updated the question with more detail!

Comment: What is `Colors.white`? That seems to cause the crash.

Comment: Nono it's not, its just a custom sutff for my colors! As I mention, if I remove this line of code the crash is on the next UI element because they are all nil i guess!! But I cant understand why

Comment: @koen if my first viewDidLoad element is     self.label.text = "HI" I get a crash here too! Beacause it's all nil!

Comment: What's the result of `return MyUIViewController()` my guess is that returns nil.

Comment: Well isnt it the correct approach to integrate UIkit and SwiftUI? What should I do then?  I mean, i'm just following what WWDC and many articles re saying @koen

Comment: You're only sharing snippets, so it is difficult to see where it goes wrong. To be able to help you it is important that you share a [example]. For instance, you are not showing what code is in `MyUIViewController` - but that's where the crash happens. It could just be a simple typo somewhere. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen i solved my problem! I tried a different approach with storyboard!

Comment: @manubrio Glad you solved it. Feel free to put a detailed solution as an answer below, so it can be useful for future readers.